# JavaFX stage popup on top of existing stage - with transparent stageStyle

Tags: user-interface, javafx-2, stage

I would like to do the following - open a new stage window (a small popup) on top of an existing stage. However, I do not want to show the border of the popup stage (with the 'x' in the corner to close).
I know that I can use `stage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT)`, but when I do that the stage is NOT on top, and it hides behind the existing stage. 
I tried setting the initOwner to the existing stage or even setting it to null. That works when the StageStyle is UTILITY, but when I change the stage style to TRANSPARENT it does not popup on top.

It seems that these two settings do not work well together and I do not know how to achieve the result I want.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there any other way to remove the border from the stage window?

```
public static void start(Stage stage) {

    //stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UTILITY);

    stage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);

    stage.initOwner(null);

    //stage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);

    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 300);

    stage.setScene(scene);

    stage.show();
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: It works for me with `StageStyle.TRANSPARENT`, `stage.initOwner(primaryStage)` and any of `Modality.*`, on my Win8 with JavaFX 2.2.45-b18. Provide your environment.

Comment: I checked again in another place in the system and it works. It seems that the problem is that right after I build the stage I retrieve data from the database which takes a few seconds. The point was to have the popup window with a progress bar or waiting indicator. When I DONT retrieve for the database right after the transparent window works, but when I do call the database - the popup only appears AFTER the retrieval returns.
why does this happen? maybe there is another way to 'freeze' the system while accessing the db instead of the popup?

Comment: Are you performing your db query on the FX thread?

Comment: @user1099607 search the site for background task executions and process indicator (loading panel) while the executions. Basically you should do your non GUI related jobs in javafx service (or task) in new thread, then update the GUI (FX) thread with the result.

Comment: I am working of windows 8, javaFX 8.
I wanted to do the following - call the transparent stage, call from the database and then close the stage. This works when the stage is NOT transparent. I don't understand why it would be affected by the StageStyle of the stage

Comment: I tried another solution - using a service to call from the database. However, I found this do be difficult as well. I got a lot of exceptions because the code after the service.start() ran before the thread completed and the elements I wanted to retrieve from the database were still null. Any suggestions???